# How to create an object from an array of strings with string splits?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of strings. I need to create an object in which the keys are the values from the strings to the left of the = symbol, and their values are the text in the string to the right of the = symbol in the string. Can you please tell me how to implement this?

```
    const testArray = ["test1=25", "test2=1", "test3=2015-01-02" ]
    
    
     const testObjects = ??? 

     // i want to get similar object
      {
        test1: "25",
        test2: "1",
        test3 : "2015-01-02",
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Object.fromEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) apprach along with `.map` to prepare entries:

```js
 const testArray = ["test1=25", "test2=1", "test3=2015-01-02" ]
 
 const entries = testArray.map(e => e.split('='));
 
 const result = Object.fromEntries(entries);
 
 console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are more optimized ways of doing this, however this does get you the result you want. *Please be aware* there is no validation here, meaning if an item in your array is missing the equals sign "=" (or any delimeter you want to use), it will fail.

```js
const testArray = ["test1=25", "test2=1", "test3=2015-01-02" ];
let testObj = {};

testArray.forEach(item => {
    testObj[item.split("=")[0]] = item.split("=")[1];
});

console.log(testObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 const testArray = ["test1=25", "test2=1", "test3=2015-01-02" ]
 let t = testArray.map((e)=>e.split('='));
 
 const obj = {};
 for (const key of t) {
      obj[key[0]] = key[1];
 }

console.log ( 'obj : ',obj);
```